# Returning a dictionary key from its value

Tags: python, function, dictionary

So I am trying to write a basic function that takes a text input and an integer 'n', and returns the words in the input that occur n times or more.

Here is what I have:

My problem is the 'return keys' line - clearly that will not work.

What can I use to return the relevant words?

Thanks

Comment: We need some examples of input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return [k for k, v in counttext.items() if v >= n]`

Comment: I'd use `iteritems` instead of `items` here.

Comment: I'm not that experienced and am not entirely certain of the difference -- is it that `items` constructs a list but `iteritems` returns a generator and avoids that up-front cost? Either way you're going through the entire dictionary, right?

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'm really new to python, could you explain the:

    k for k, v in
part to me?

Comment: @grayshirt This is actually the correct thing to do under Python 3 anyway, since `items` now returns a generator and `iteritems` is removed.

Comment: @129893289: That's a list comprehension (Google that term for plenty of tutorials on the syntax). What it does is 1) call `counttext.items()`, a method all dictionaries have that returns each key-value pair as a tuple; 2) iterate over those tuples, unpacking their contents into the variables `k` and `v` 3) test whether each `v` is greater than or equal to `n` and 4) if so, add the corresponding `k` to the resulting list. So `k for k, v` means that we're building our list out of the values of `k`, which are the keys of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
counttext = collections.Counter(ltext)
result = []
for key in counttext:
    if counttext[key] >= n:
        result.append(key)
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7, you can revert your dictionary with [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and after get the key from the value.

For example with a simple `dict`:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> revert_d = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}
>>> revert_d
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
>>> revert_d[1]
'a'
```